# How to Align Heading to the center of Navigation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a heading inside a navigation like below 
I am trying to align the Heading to the center of navigation.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <h1>My Heading</h1> 
</nav>
```

When I use the CSS like the below

```
.navbar{
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  text-align: center;
}
```

it does not align the text inside the navbar to be center instead it aligns to left. I also tried adding CSS for h1. It doesnot work too.
What am I missing?.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: and you can try aligning your `h1` in the center of `navbar`

Comment: Check the specifity order. You might have on your page/css a much important class which aligns the h1 to left.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

This is similiar to this question: [Bootstrap center heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155046/bootstrap-center-heading)

bootstrap has added three css classes for text align.

```
.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
.navbar h1 {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

If your h1 is styled as a block element, it will definitely be aligned center

Answer (score 0):

Your example just works fine! However it might be that you need to set the width to the navbar.

```css
.navbar{
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <h1>My Heading</h1> 
</nav>
```

Comment: It is working when I test in JSFiddle but not in my angular application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

or, please add a class to the h1 tag and write css like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <h1 class="heading">My Heading</h1> 
</nav>

nav.navbar.navbar-default h1.heading {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
nav > h1
{
   text-align:center !important;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
nav > h1
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none; 
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `!important` instead make use of css specificity.

Comment: @bhansa, why so?

Comment: Doesn't it simply override the existing CSS only for specified classes/tags?

Comment: It's fine for this example, but when you have a big application its better to use css selectors properly instead overriding anything.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, thanks, I appreciate the advice.